# PHP - how to exclude Non-working hours from SLA calculation

Tags: php

I want to define SLA for given task excluding weekends, holidays and non working hours in PHP .Workdays Mon-Fri and Worktime 9AM to 5PM.
How can i define SLA and calculate time taken to complete the task in PHP?

Comment: Show what have you tried? If you researched anything or not? SO members would be glad to help if you show that you actually tried.

Answer (score 0):

Edit Question :
Here the code that I tried, i can exclude the weekends and holidays. But want exclude non working time as well

function _getBusinessDayOfMonth($startDate,$businessDays,$holidays)
{

```
$date = strtotime($startDate);
$i = 0;

while($i < $businessDays)
{
    //get number of week day (1-7)
    $day = date('N',$date);
    //get just Y-m-d date
    $dateYmd = date("Y-m-d",$date);
    $datehis=date("H:i:s",$date);
    if($day < 6 && !in_array($dateYmd, $holidays)){
        $i++;
    }       
    $date = strtotime($dateYmd . ' +1 day'.$datehis);
}       
$day = date('N',$date);
$d=date("Y-m-d",$date);
if( $day==7||in_array($d, $holidays))
{
    $date = strtotime($d . ' +1 day'.$datehis);
}
elseif($day==6)
{
    $date = strtotime($d . ' +2 day'.$datehis);
}


//return date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date);
return date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date);
```

}